# Solr DataImportHandler CachedSqlEntityProcessor ClassCastException

Tags: solr, classcastexception, dataimporthandler

I am using `Solr 4.6.0` and trying to import my data using `CachedSqlEntityProcessor`, but somehow I end up getting a `ClassCastException`.

**Schema**

```
<fields>
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="conference" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="year" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="doi" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
   <field name="text" type="text_en_shingling" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 </fields>
```

**Data config**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="mysql" type="JdbcDataSource" 
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url="..." 
        batchSize="-1" 
        user="..." password="..." />
    <document name="publications">
        <entity name="publication" query="
            SELECT
                sm_publications.id AS p_id,
                sm_publications.year AS p_year,
                sm_publications.doi AS p_doi,
                CONCAT(sm_publications.title, ' ', sm_publications.abstract) AS p_text,
                sm_publications.conference_id 
            FROM sm_publications 
            WHERE '${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false' OR 
                modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="p_id" name="id" />
            <field column="p_text" name="text" />
            <field column="p_year" name="year" />
            <field column="p_doi" name="doi" />

            <entity name="conference" query="SELECT id AS CID,full_name FROM sm_conferences"
                processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" cacheKey="CID" cacheLookup="publication.conference_id">
                <field column="full_name" name="conference" />
            </entity>

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**Error message**

```
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:710)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:63)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:495)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SortedMapBackedCache.iterator(SortedMapBackedCache.java:147)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DIHCacheSupport.getIdCacheData(DIHCacheSupport.java:179)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DIHCacheSupport.getCacheData(DIHCacheSupport.java:145)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    ... 38 more
```

**Table structure**
[image]

Comment: I think you would need to put mysql-connector-java-5.1.*.jar to lib folder.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the connection. If I remove the entity `conference`, everything works fine. That means that the entity `publication` is processed successfully.

Comment: Did you try any of the suggested solutions? Did one help? Or really neither of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CachedSqlEntityProcessor relies on [DIHCacheSupport](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DIHCacheSupport.java?view=markup)(`Map<String,Object> getIdCacheData(...)` ) that is not adapted to work with keys of type Integer, which is expected behavior for any cache. (`Object key = context.resolve(cacheForeignKey);`, this key should really be of type String)

```
SELECT CAST(id as CHAR(32)) AS CID,full_name FROM sm_conferences
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem of the ClassCastException, but unfortunately the tables were not joined. That means that although the error was gone, no `conferences` could be imported. That means that there must be more errors to be found...

Comment: I actually made another thread with a more general purpose - ways of increasing the import performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841186/solr-4-6-0-dataimporthandler-speed-up-performance

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of case. You need to write the key in the cacheLookup attribute in upper-case. If you use

```
cacheLookup="publication.CONFERENCE_ID"
```

it will work.

All columns you gather for the entity `publication` are gathered within a Map internally. The keys to that map are uppercased. When you write `cacheLookup="publication.CONFERENCE_ID"` that short part after the equals sign `publication.CONFERENCE_ID` is a short-cut to that map. Apparently a `String#toUpper` is missing at some point in between.

---

I have added a test case about this, have a look [at the DIHCachedTest](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/DIHCachedTest.java), check it out and let it run. You will need maven for this. I create an embedded HSQLDB that mimics your schema and run an embedded Solr that does have 2 data-import configurations.

- src/main/resources/solr/dih-cached/conf/data-config-fault.xml
- src/main/resources/solr/dih-cached/conf/data-config.xml

The first one is used for the test case [DIHCachedTest#runImportWithFault](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/DIHCachedTest.java#L78). This will run into the same error you have posted in your question.

The second one is used for the test case [DIHCachedTest#runImport](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/DIHCachedTest.java#L72). This will succeed.

If you compare both configurations, you will see that the only difference is the case of 
`cacheLookup="publication.CONFERENCE_ID"` vs `cacheLookup="publication.conference_id"`.

---

The issue [SOLR-2483 DIH - an uppercase problem in query parameters](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2483) describes this bug pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is a regression coming out of the introduction of pluggable cache support in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2382 and the workaround (working for me) is to cast to strings in all columns that you will use as either keys or values. In PostgreSQL cast syntax:

```
<entity name="par" dataSource="d" query="SELECT id, xyz, child_id::text FROM par;">
  <entity name="child" dataSource="d" query="SELECT id::text, abc FROM child;"
          processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor"
          where="id=par.child_id"/>
</entity>
```

(and in other DBs I guess you need `CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)` or such instead of `id::text`).

Comment: Oh, whoops, Ion Cojocaru has essentially the same answer, posted earlier; he should get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is something wrong with your dataimporthandler configuration, I had rather check that your database types match your corresponding sold field type

Something like a database type resulting in a java.lang.Integer is passed to a solr field based on java.lang.String

OUPS, I might have got it wrong, is your uniqueKey field for SOLR still "id"? you've set in your schema this field as being an integer, which is a bad idea.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field

> "Note that if you have enabled the QueryElevationComponent in
>   solrconfig.xml it requires the schema to have a uniqueKey of type
>   StrField. It cannot be, for example, an int field."

Comment: can you share your table structure?

Comment: I've just updated my question and added a graphical database structure. My `uniqueKey` is still an integer, but the `ClassCastException` only occurs if I include the `conference` entity. If I remove it from my `dataconfig`, the import process ends successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Solr CachedSqlEntityProcessor is depreciated somewhere around version 4.5. The new syntax uses cacheImpl, cacheKey & cacheLookup

I had to update the SQL in my data-config.xml

Old Syntax

```
processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor"
where="fkId=parentTable.parentId"
```

New Syntax

```
cacheKey="fkId" cacheLookup="parenttable.parentId" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache"
```

See full latest Solr wiki info, the old DataImportHanlder page is out of date https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-EntityProcessors