# Solr dataimport handler cacheImpl does not retrieve rows

Tags: mysql, solr

I am currently working on a dataimport handler that retrieves data from MySQL for quick searching. It consists of the import of a root entity `CabinCategoryFares` and a few child entities (`Cruise`, `RouteDay`, `Ship`).

This import works, but is very slow as the relation between e.g. `CabinCategoryFares` and `Cruise` is many-to-one so there are many identical queries on `Cruise` fired.

To alleviate this, I am trying to implement the `SortedMapBackedCache` caching on the child entities. Below a snippet, the original is quite big.

```
<document name="Cruises">
  <entity name="CabinCategoryFare" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="SELECT CabinCategoryFare.cruise_id FROM CabinCategoryFare">
    <entity name="Cruise"  cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" cacheKey="Cruise.id" cacheLookup="CabinCategoryFare.cruise_id"query="SELECT Cruise.id FROM Cruise">
    </entity>
  </entity>`
```

This returns `NULL` for every field that is read from `Cruise`. I can tell from the logs that the `dataimporthandler` is running the `Cruise` query, but it just isn't returning any results or any errors after that. It seems it isn't able to find any hits on the `cacheLookup`, but logging in the `DIHCacheSupport` class is non-existant and I'm at a total loss what's happening, or rather why it isn't happening.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problems:
1. Bug in Solr/DIHCacheSupport.java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21732907/3012497
(cacheKey gets uppercased somewhere in the process, cacheLookup does not so one needs to always use an uppercase cacheLookup)
2. The query for the Cruise entity uses a grouping function (GROUP_CONCAT), but didn't have a GROUP BY clause. This wasn't a problem uncached (because of the WHERE clause) but would still only return one row without where.
3. DIHCacheSupport seems to only work with string keys, int key will cause an exception that does not show up in the logs.

Hope this might save someone a few hours.